# "need to" pronounced something like /neit/ here, Why?

Tags: pronunciation

Watch [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D8HYfcUDR4qw&ved=2ahUKEwjdsP2NndbcAhVGb1AKHTNwBPE4ChCjtAEwAnoECAEQBw&usg=AOvVaw1nMTuZXnL98BQkHCWBYtmm) video, 00:16 .

How do you pronounce "need to"? /niːd tə/ or /neɪt/ I think the professor said something like /neɪt/ in that video.
The sentence:

> You **need to** be aware of its difference between skeletal muscle and smooth muscle.

I wanted to know if the professor didn't even say "need to" and said something else that I've misunderstood?

Comment: Lots of speakers elide the /d/ in the collocation ***need to*** in certain spoken contexts - or more precisely, they reduce it to something like a glottal stop, with the briefest of pauses before continuing with the **/t/** in ***to*** (which I'd say is *rarely* reduced in BrE, but I think some AmE speakers would happily reduce the **/d/ + /t/** sequence to just **/d/**).

Comment: @FumbleFingers +1 but is this a response, or a comment?

Comment: It's a comment. I don't have audio right now, so I haven't listened to your link. But I'm really just making the point that it *might* be relevant whether the speaker has a BrE or AmE accent.

Comment: @FumbleFingers but what about /n**eɪ**t/, why it's not /n**i**ːt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /i:/ to /ei/ is a feature of the Australian accent.

The elision of the /d/ and /t/ is common is spoken contexts. Consonants with the same articulation become merged.  The /u/ of "to" is also reduced to a schwa in this unstressed syllable.  The result is that what an slowly speak RP speaker would say /'ni:d tu bi:/ becomes /neitbi/ or something similar.

In other words this is just how Aussies talk.

Comment: If you've seen the movie that I sent, did you recognize that the professor has an Australian accent?

Comment: Yes, he sounds Australian to me.

Comment: I wonder if he says **you were looking** or **you are looking**. It's in 03:16. If you don't find it a problem, could you please check this out?